# Sublime text 3 elimina las clases declaradas con "use" en PHP

Tags: php, sublimetext3

Cuando escribo un código cómo el siguiente:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
```

Y guardo me elimina las clases que traigo con la función use, ¿porque será?

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema. Instalé la paqueteria de CodeFormatter para que me ayudara con la indentación automática de mi código, entonves cuando pongo el código en el orden mostrado arriba me elimina las clases.

La solución fue ingresar a **Preferences -> Package settings -> CodeFormatter -> Settings - Default**. Una vez que abrió el archivo de configuración buscamos "passes" y dentro de los corchetes le agregamos **"OnlyOrderUseClauses"** y listo!